# Authorization using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

My task is to login to the application using spring-security concept.
I'm able to login using Spring security but it's only for "ROLE_ADMIN"(because i've included ( `<user name="Sriram" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />` ) in spring-security.xml .,

So only Sriram can login to the application.  Now my question is, I should login to the application using below credential (`<user name="Yogesh" password="12345" authorities="DIRECT_CUSTOMER" />`). That means validation should happen for the particular users.

- Case 1: If Sriram logs in -> He can see only his authorized next page.
- Case 2: If Yogesh logs in -> He can see only his authorized next page.

That means, it has to validate in spring-security.xml for the login.

This is my spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
        <intercept-url pattern="/"  access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />  
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>  
   <authentication-provider>  
     <user-service>  
  <user name="Sriram" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />  
  <!--  <user name="Vignesh" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> -->
<!--   <user name="Yogesh" password="12345" authorities="PARTNER_CUSTOMER" />  -->
     </user-service>  
   </authentication-provider>  
 </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the validation will happen only for the users provided in spring-security.xml

```
<user-service>  
  <user name="Sriram" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />  
  <user name="Vignesh" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
  <user name="Yogesh" password="12345" authorities="PARTNER_CUSTOMER" />
 </user-service>
```

you don't have to comment out the other users. Just while logging In provide the credentials & the security framework will match the entered details against the entries under `<user-service>` tag.

In case of a large number of users you can create a user database & fetch the details from there under `<user-service>` tag. Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/)

You can set role based access control. Every user will have his respective roles & then you can map ant style url as per the role. See the below example code

```
<http auto-config="true">  
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403page" />  
  <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
  <form-login login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"  
   password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/user"  
   authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />  
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />  
 </http>
```

Users having specific roles will only be able to access the urls mapped as per roles. So  Vignesh won't be able to access the url `/admin**` he will only be able to access `/user**`

Comment: Thank you friend :)   Say, Sriram is a superAdmin. So, he can only see his related next jsp file. Say, Yogesh is MasterAdmin, So, he can see only his related next jsp file. Say, Vignesh is User, So he should see only his related next jsp page.. How do I implement this here ?? I want idea

Comment: What changes I've to do in spring-security.xml. I mean here in this line                                                                                                                 <intercept-url pattern="/"  access="ROLE_USER"/>

Comment: Hi, I have kind of other problems also in spring_security. I want you to be in touch with me buddy. Let's solve it. Your mail id please

Comment: You can post the questions here. https://www.facebook.com/shivang.sarawagi my fb id

Comment: Hi friend, Login is working for me for me for differenent set of users with hardcoded values in Spring-security.xml. Now I've to login using database. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer I found.
worked spring-security.xml is here below

```
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />

 <user-service>  
  <user name="Sriram" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
   <user name="Yogesh" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
  <user name="Vignesh" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
   <user name="Shruti" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
   <user name="Umesh" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> 
  </user-service>
```

and I controlled it in HomeController.java for validating users to post them to their authorized pages.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

            User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String name = user.getUsername();
            System.out.println(name);
            String password=user.getPassword();
            System.out.println(password);
            if(name.equals("Sriram") && (password.equals("12345"))){
                return "post-login_SoXAdmin";
            }else if(name.equals("Yogesh") && (password.equals("12345"))){
                return "post-login_directCustomerAdmin";
            }else if(name.equals("Vignesh") && (password.equals("12345"))){
                return "post-login_PartnerAdmin";
            }else if(name.equals("Shruti") && (password.equals("12345"))){
                return "post-login_directCustomerUser";
            }else if(name.equals("Umesh") && (password.equals("12345"))){
                return "post-login_partnerUser";
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("No set of credential found, Please register");
            }
            System.out.println("1" +name);
            System.out.println("SoX_Admin_Page");
            model.addAttribute("username", name);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security login + database example");
            return "post-login";
        }
```